# Adding primary key as a part of INSERT INTO table VALUES query

Tags: mysql

Just for demonstration purposes. I have two tables "quiz" and "question".

The **quiz table** contains the following columns

- quiz_id (PK)
- quiz_title

The **question table** contains the following columns

- question_id (PK)
- quiz_ID (FK)
- question_text

I am trying to insert the question text into "question_text" in the question table.

I can successfully retrieve the latest quiz_id and insert it into the question table.

```
INSERT INTO question (quiz_id) SELECT max(quiz_id) FROM quiz
```

But I also need to add the question text. I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO question (question_text) VALUES ("question_text_sample")
```

But I am getting an error because the FK info (quiz_id) is not provided in the query.

I would like to combine the queries above but I can't figure out a working solution.

I tried the following:

```
INSERT INTO quiz (quiz_title) values ("quiz_title_sample")
INSERT INTO question (quiz_id, question_text) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), "question_text")
```

another try:

```
INSERT INTO question (quiz_id, question_text) VALUES (SELECT max(quiz_id) FROM quiz , "question_text_sample")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, this should be it

```
INSERT INTO question (quiz_id, question_text) SELECT max(quiz_id), "question_text_sample" FROM quiz
```

More on the `INSERT` Syntax: **http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html**

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to do the insert into quiz first (because of the FK relationship, as you noted).

Can't you store the LAST_INSERT_ID() in a user variable and then do a INSERT INTO...SELECT (sorry, not as familiar with MySQL)?

Comment: Yes, the insert into the quiz is actually included in my question.
I realize it doesn't stand out very much. But I do insert data into the quiz table first before trying to add data into the question table.

The solution provided by Akash worked well for me. 
Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Is your quiz_id an AUTO_INCREMENT (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html)?

INSERT INTO quiz (quiz_title) values ('quiz_title_sample')

INSERT INTO question (quiz_id, question_text) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'question text')

Comment: Yes, the quiz_id is an auto_increment (in the quiz table).
The solution provided by Akash worked well for me. Thanks for your input.